# Sharepoint alerts not being sent

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office

I have a sharepoint site and I have contributor access to the site. I am trying to create alerts for documents and folders in the site. When I create an alert, I do get an email saying that an alert has been created but when I edit the doc, I do not get any alert. Can someone tell me whats going on here? I tried googling, but I get complicated answers which I do not understand. I am fairly new to sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any spam filtering in place?  Check to make sure the alerts aren't in there.  Otherwise, I suggest using a ULS monitoring tool to check the ULS logs for any errors that may have been generated by the event that should have triggered an alert. I use one called [ULS Viwewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer).

Comment: I do not have any spam filters and I am not allowed to use third party software on the laptop that I am using :(
Any other way I can figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: You can read the ULS logs directly.  It's messy but can be done.  Are you running SharePoint on your laptop? If not, do you have access to the server on which it is running?  The logs are in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Comment: I don't even know what to do with the tool

Comment: Once you you have ULS Viewer installed on your SharePoint server, you can use it to search your ULS logs or see new entries as they are written to the logs.  You can either run the viewer and create an alert to see if any errors occurred, or view past log files to try to find the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide - may help

http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

See "Which best describes your symptoms? - Getting initial Confirmation Emails but no Alert Emails"

which then talks you through

- Check email infrastructure
- Check SharePoint timer Jobs
- Check list permissions